# How to set widget opacity in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Has tkinter opacity like HTML?if you do HTML you understand what I say.I searched a lot in google, but I didn't find my answer.If you know help me,please.

Comment: Here is the correct method to set individual widget opacity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77850151/16813096

Answer (score -1):

> Has tkinter opacity like HTML

No, it does not. The only setting you have is the opacity of the window as a whole. You can't set the opacity of individual widgets.

Comment: `root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.8)`?

Comment: @Max: that only works for the window as a whole, not individual widgets. I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley so that means, there is no way to use `root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.1)` and have opaque widgets?

Comment: @CoolCloud: that will make the entire window opaque. You can't control individual widgets.